# Anyway to use the map data from this website for SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, 3dslam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://data.selfracingcars.com/

I was using RTABMAP before since I wanted to be able to differentiate between the green patch of grass and the actual track (which Lidar wouldn't be able to do as it won't hit anything). But it doesn't look like it does that. Was wondering if there was a more appropriate package that makes use of any of the map data from that website.

Edit: Here are examples of some of the races for this track: https://youtu.be/KmOakRbBGFM, https://youtu.be/Z6Hc2aD7tJQ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366097/anyway-to-use-the-map-data-from-this-website-for-slam?/) by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2020-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you want to play PCAP data on ROS, see this page:
https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2019/05/displaying-velodyne-pcap-data-in-ros.html

For an example with [RTAB-Map](https://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) (>=0.20.7 built with [libpointmatcher](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher) support), based on this [ouster example](http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Ouster-drive-under-the-rain-td6496.html), you can try the following:

1. Play a PCAP (I tried the 1.4 GB one):

   roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch pcap:=$HOME/Downloads/velodyne/2016-05-28hdl32.pcap read_once:=true rpm:=1200
2. Add a `base_link` to make x-axis of the car forward (lidar is looking right)

   rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 -1.570796327 0 0 base_link velodyne 100
3. Start mapping:

   roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch    
   use_sim_time:=false 
   depth:=false 
   subscribe_scan_cloud:=true 
   frame_id:=base_link 
   scan_cloud_topic:=/velodyne_points 
   scan_topic:=/disabled 
   scan_cloud_max_points:=34750  
   scan_cloud_assembling:=true 
   scan_cloud_assembling_time:=0.5 
   scan_cloud_assembling_voxel_size:=0.5 
   icp_odometry:=true 
   approx_sync:=false 
   args:="-d  
   --RGBD/CreateOccupancyGrid false 
   --RGBD/ProximityMaxGraphDepth 0 
   --RGBD/ProximityPathMaxNeighbors 5 
   --RGBD/LocalRadius 30 
   --RGBD/ProximityMaxPaths 1 
   --Rtabmap/DetectionRate 0 
   --Icp/PM true 
   --Icp/VoxelSize 0.5   
   --Icp/MaxTranslation 10   
   --Icp/MaxCorrespondenceDistance 1.5 
   --Icp/PMOutlierRatio 0.7 
   --Icp/Iterations 30 
   --Icp/PointToPlane true 
   --Icp/PMMatcherKnn 3 
   --Icp/PMMatcherEpsilon 1 
   --Icp/PMMatcherIntensity true 
   --Icp/Epsilon 0.0001 
   --Icp/PointToPlaneK 10 
   --Icp/PointToPlaneRadius 0 
   --Icp/CorrespondenceRatio 0.2 
   --Icp/PointToPlaneGroundNormalsUp 0.8 
   --Icp/PointToPlaneMinComplexity 0.0" 
   odom_args:="
   --Odom/ScanKeyFrameThr 0.7 
   --OdomF2M/ScanMaxSize 10000  
   --OdomF2M/ScanSubtractRadius 0.5   
   --Icp/Iterations 10 
   --Icp/CorrespondenceRatio 0.01 
   --Icp/MaxTranslation 2   
   --Icp/PMOutlierRatio 0.4 
   --Icp/PointToPlane false"

Here are some results:
[image: image description]

Colored with intensity from LiDAR:

[image: image description]

LiDAR Odometry-only (red lines are loop closures):

[image: image description]

With loop closure optimization:

[image: image description]

To distinguish the track and the grass, the velodyne's intensity channel can give a good idea. We can see it more clearly in this video: https://youtu.be/hmtdcxV-0NU

The parameters above are quite very for this dataset to close the loops without a camera. Combining with a stereo camera could help to detect loop closures more robustly.

**EDIT**

Integrating a stereo camera is possible (assuming it is already calibrated, synchronized between left and right cameras and provide [common stereo topics](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoHandHeldMapping)). You could add to `rtabmap.launch` command above:

```
stereo:=true \ 
rgbd_sync:=true \
approx_sync:=true \
approx_rgbd_sync:=false \
left_image_topic:=/stereo_camera/left/image_rect \
right_image_topic:=/stereo_camera/right/image_rect \
left_camera_info_topic:=/stereo_camera/left/camera_info \
right_camera_info_topic:=/stereo_camera/right/camera_info
```

This will synchronize stereo data with Lidar data. You may also do stereo visual odometry instead of LiDAR odometry, I think it would be a little more robust because of the lack of geometry in this kind of environment. To use stereo odometry, remove `icp_odometry:=true` above and set back `--Rtabmap/DetectionRate 2`. As I did for Lidar, there could be some tunings for visual parameters depending on the resolution of the cameras and this kind of environment. If you want to use external odometry from another visual odometry package, add:

```
visual_odometry:=false \
odom_topic:=/my_visual_odometry_topic
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on 2020-11-29**:
Wow that is amazing. I didn't think the Lidar information could actually be useful like that. How do you recommend combining it with a stereo camera? Like would RTABMAP do it automatically or would I have to change a parameter

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-11-29**:
I edited the answer :)

**Comment by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on 2020-11-29**:
Thanks! Just curious but this is likely not possible if we use a 2D Lidar right. The intensity channels and stuff come from the fact that the Velodyne Lidar is a 3D Lidar. So we would have to rely more on a stereo map or is there a way to use this 3D data with a 2D Lidar?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-11-29**:
With a 2D lidar tilted, it could be possible along with stereo odometry to assemble them in 3D. Some 2D lidars (like SICK) have also an intensity (or reflectivity) channel.

**Comment by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on 2020-12-01**:
I have a Intel Realsense D455 camera. Was wondering if it was possible to use this data but by converting the depthscans of the Realsense to Laserscans to follow this data

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-12-10**:
No, use rtabmap as stereo slam directly (or rgb-d slam when using depth image from the camera). Those parameters are really tuned for ring-like lidars like velodyne or ouster.